# When does ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor reject execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

If the queue is unbounded, will it ever call the RejectedExecutionHandler?

From the documentation:

> New tasks submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable) will be rejected when the Executor has been shut down, and also when the Executor uses finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue capacity, and is saturated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation link you posted says it all. If you specify finite bounds or the queue is shutdown then the `RejectedExecutionHandler` is called. If the queue is unbounded (and I assume not shutdown) then it will never call the `RejectedExecutionHandler`.

You can set a handler that just calls back to the queue if there is any question.  I use something like:

```
// set a handler that just calls back to the queue which will block the submitter
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
   public void rejectedExecution(Runnable runnable, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
      // this will block if the queue is full
      executor.getQueue().put(runnable);
   }
});
```

Comment: So, since ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor uses unbounded queues and, assuming the queue is not shut down, this custom handler will never be called?

Comment: E.g. from the Javadoc of #delayedExecute:
..   If pool is shut down, rejects the task. ...